# Подключение gulpfile.js

Tags: gulp, sass, консоль, gulp-sass

при попытке подсоеденить галп, выдаёт ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто может сказать как это избежать?

```
Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\Work\gulpfile.js C:\Users\Vic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.‌​js:129 gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
 ^ 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined 
at C:\Users\Vic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.‌​js:129:20 
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7) 
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9) 
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:678:11) 
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16) at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Comment: Замнните картинку текстом.

Comment: [03:08:26] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\Work\gulpfile.js
C:\Users\Vic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129
    gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Vic\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:678:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3

Comment: дополните вопрос, отредактируйте код, ваш комментарий не читабелен

Comment: Дополнил вопрос